# PostgreSQL network address range query optimize

Tags: database, postgresql, query-optimization

Below is the table structure with about 6 million records:

```
CREATE TABLE "ip_loc" (
  "start_ip" inet,
  "end_ip" inet,
  "iso2" varchar(4),
  "state" varchar(100),
  "city" varchar(100) 
);

CREATE INDEX "index_ip_loc" on ip_loc using gist(iprange(start_ip,end_ip));
```

***It takes about 1 second to do the query.***

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE select * from ip_loc where iprange(start_ip,end_ip)@>'180.167.1.25'::inet;

Bitmap Heap Scan on ip_loc (cost=1080.76..49100.68 rows=28948 width=41) (actual time=1039.428..1039.429 rows=1 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (iprange(start_ip, end_ip) @> '180.167.1.25'::inet)
  Heap Blocks: exact=1
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_ip_loc (cost=0.00..1073.53 rows=28948 width=0) (actual time=1039.411..1039.411 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (iprange(start_ip, end_ip) @> '180.167.1.25'::inet) Planning time: 0.090 ms Execution time: 1039.466 ms
```

iprange is a customized type:

```
CREATE TYPE iprange AS RANGE (
    SUBTYPE = inet
);
```

Is there a way to do the query faster?

Comment: There is a pretty big discrepancy between the expected rows and the actual rows for the index scan. Does this change if you run `analyze ip_loc`? The long scan time _might_ indicate you are suffering from index bloat. Does this improve if you rebuild the index using `reindex`?

Answer (score 1):

These ranges are non-overlapping? I'd try to btree index `end_ip` and do:

```
with candidate as (
  select * from ip_loc
  where end_ip<='38.167.1.53'::inet
  order by end_ip desc
  limit 1
)
select * from candidate
where start_ip<='38.167.1.53'::inet;
```

Works in 0.1ms on 4M rows on my computer.

Remember to analyze table after populating it with data.

Comment: Then try this improved query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: previous version wasn't nearly that fast, so this comment was then appropriate

Answer (score 0):

The `inet` type is a composite type and not the simple 32-bits needed to construct an IPv4 address; it includes a netmask for instance. That makes storage, indexing and retrieval needlessly complex **if all you are interested in is actual IP addresses** (i.e. the 32 bit of the actual address, as opposed to addresses with netmasks, such as you would get from a web server listing the clients of an app) and you do not manipulate the IP addresses inside the database. If that is the case, you could store your `start_ip` and `end_ip` as simple integers and operate on those using simple integer comparison. (The same can be done for IPv6 addresses using an `integer[4]` data type.)

A point to keep in mind is that [the default range constructor behaviour is to include the lower bound and **exclude the upper bound**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRUCT) so in your index and query the actual `end_ip` is not included.

Lastly, if you stick with a range type, on your index you should add the [`range_ops` operator class](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/gist-builtin-opclasses.html) for maximum performance.

Answer (score 0):

Add a clustered index for end_ip only

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but this is the solution.

- Refrain from using start_ip and end_ip directly. Why? Because even if you use and index on those two columns, there is no guarantee that postgres will leverage that index. If too many rows are **expected** (not actually) to be returned by the query planner, it will use a sequential scan of rows, which we want to avoid at all costs
- Instead, use one pre-processing step: when loading your data merge the two columns into a single subnet and store that in another inet column. This is easy to do even after your table is created by doing:

```sql
ALTER TABLE ip_loc ADD COLUMN subnet inet;
CREATE INDEX ON ip_loc USING gist (subnet inet_ops);
UPDATE ip_loc SET SUBNET = inet_merge(start_ip, end_ip);
```

Note the creation of an index on the new column, and populating it using the magical `inet_merge` function

Now your queries can be changed to querying "contained in the subnet" rather than "between two inets", which from a query analyzer point of view is expected to return a lot fewer rows - so it will use the index we created above, leading to much faster queries, for example:

```sql
select * from ip_loc where '180.167.1.25'::inet << subnet;
```

The above went from approx 1s to under 10ms using the approach above